# How can I ensure a specific background worker thread executes before another one?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, thread-priority

I have a WPF application with **two** background worker threads that operate while loading.

The first one (**bw1**) is spawned at application start, and the second one (**bw2**) is spawned after some time has elapsed.

I am in a situation that I CAN'T spawn the second background worker (**bw2**) from the first one's (**bw1**) "worker_completed".

Currently, I have a class-level bool variable (default `false`), and set it `true` in **bw1**'s worker_completed.

And at the starting of **bw2**, I have a check to see if the above bool is false, and if so, **bw2** will sleep for 100 milliseconds.

This works, for the most part. I'd like to improve it.

- Can I use thread priority in **bw1** (set it as highest, say) to ensure that **bw1** is executed while **bw2** sleeps?
- Is there an event-driven way I can accomplish this goal?

Comment: I don't know wpf but worker/thread's priority should never be used for scheduling tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Busy spinning (even with sleep) is a bad idea when you don't actually know when the event will occur, since you are checking blindly and using system resources unnecessarily.

Use an `AutoResetEvent` instead. At the beginning of bw2's code call `ev.WaitOne()` and in bw1's `work_completed` call `ev.Set()` to release bw2:

```
AutoResetEvent ev = new AutoResetEvent();

// bw1's work completed     
private void bw1_workCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ev.Set(); // release bw2 from waiting
}

// bw2's do work
private void bw2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ev.WaitOne(); // wait for the signal from bw1
    // code
}
```

Comment: ev.WaitOne -> while doing so, can we make sure that it will execute bw1 ?

Comment: @Relativity: when executing `ev.WaitOne` the thread is taken off the CPU and not scheduled again until `ev.Set` is called. Practically it is suspended, so bw1 is free to execute.